# Data structure to design a media player and play them in random order

Tags: data-structures, media-player

I am designing a media player and I want to store songs and play them in random order

**a)** which data structure I should you use to store songs?

**b)** how I will select the next song randomly to play in a way which prevents the same song being played until all songs are once played.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1)In my view, you can take a map whose key will be the song number and value will be the actual media file.

2)Take a vector of the same size of the number of songs.

As songs keep on getting stored in the map, increment the counter 'cnt' like-

songs[cnt++] = Song1.mp3

Similarly for rest of the songs.

Assign a vector, lets say we name it as 'hash', and it is initialized with 0

3) Now create a new function searchSong which will choose a random value from 1 to cnt and check whether corresponding index in 'hash' is set or not ,if not then set that index with 1 so that if same random value comes again then same song is not played and call a playSong function as through map you can use the "value" regarding this random number, if 'hash' at this index is set you can simply call the searchSong function again and not play the same song.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with this is you need to call searchSong again and again. Imagine you have played 20 songs and there are 25 songs in total. In this case, searchSong would be called a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Use an array data structure and manipulate the positions of items.

If using C++ or numpy in Python, they have an inbuilt function called random permutation which can be used for randomizing a set of items.

---

C++

```
for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

// using built-in random generator:
std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );
```

---

Python

```
>>> np.random.permutation(10)
array([1, 7, 4, 3, 0, 9, 2, 5, 8, 6])

>>> np.random.permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([15,  1,  9,  4, 12])
```

---

And once the randomized permutation is played, we can ask for another permutation.

Probably what you are looking for is **Fisher-Yates Shuffle** algorithm.

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n - 1 downto 1 do
       j = random integer with 0 <= j <= i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Explained in detail here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-a-random-permutation-of-1-to-n/

Comment: Your code prevents the same song from being played twice in a row, but that's not what the OP asked for. He wants to have all songs play once before any song is played again.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate `songs data structure` from `played/not-played data structure`. Because you don't want to alter `song data structure` when one song is played.

Basic idea is picking random `songId` from `playIds`. `playIds` contains all ids of the songs, such that when song is played, it is put at the end of list. So first elements are not played, last elements in `playIds` are played. The reason of this is, we can pick random un-played song easily by `randomInt(0, lastPlayIndex)`, you always get un-played song (no need to regenerate random again).

The other thing is, `getSongList()`. When consumer wants list of all songs, consumer needs to sort based on needs (asc/desc by song name...) and cache preferably.

```
val songs:   Map<String, Song>  // "id1" - (song1, id1)
val playIds: List<String>       // [0, 1, 4, 2]
var lastPlayIndex = -1          // songIds after this index (including) are played

// O(1)
fun addSong(song: Song):
    if (songs.containsKey(song.id)) return // duplicate

    songs[song.id] = song

    // add to end -> swap (lastAddIndex, lastPlayIndex)
    playIds.add(song.id)
    if (lastPlayIndex != -1):
        swapPlayIndex(playIds.size-1, lastPlayIndex)
        lastPlayIndex += 1

    size += 1

// O(N)
fun removeSong(id: String):
    val song = songs[id]
    if (song == null) return // does not exist

    songs.remove(id)

    val removeIndex = playIds.indexOf(id) // O(N)
    if (lastPlayIndex == -1 || removeIndex >= lastPlayIndex):
        playIds.removeAt(removeIndex)

        // last played song is removed, so lastPlayIndex is reset
        if ((playIds.size - 1) < lastPlayIndex)
            lastPlayIndex = -1
    else:
        playIds.removeAt(removeIndex)
        lastPlayIndex -= 1

    size -= 1

// O(1)
fun playRandomSong(): Song?
    if (playIds.isEmpty()) return null  // no song available
    if (lastPlayIndex == 0) return null // all songs are played

    val from = 0
    val until = if (lastPlayIndex == -1) playIds.size else lastPlayIndex
    val randomIndex = Random.nextInt(from, until)
    val randomSongId = playIds[randomIndex]

    if (lastPlayIndex != -1):
        // there is played song before
        swapPlayIndex(randomIndex, lastPlayIndex - 1)
        lastPlayIndex -= 1
    else:
        // this is first played song
        swapPlayIndex(randomIndex, playIds.size - 1)
        lastPlayIndex = playIds.size - 1

    return songs[randomSongId]

 fun play(id: String): Song?

 fun getList(ascName: Boolean): List<Song>
```